# PATCH throws "unknown field" error

Tags: python, eve

I tried the following curl PATCH command on my against my eve framework.

```
curl -H "If-Match: b3f22da69737476d99f0863bfe8ad9a93ffa5104" -X PATCH -i http://localhost:5000/customer/5504f69f70761427d19368ba -d '{"customername":"sam"}'
```

I got the following error:

```
HTTP/1.0 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 79
Server: Eve/0.5 Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.2
Date: Sun, 15 Mar 2015 05:11:06 GMT

{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"[{\"customername\":\"sam\"}": "unknown field"}}
```

I have a customername field in my schema. I was able to successfully insert data using the command

```
curl -d '[{"customername": "john", "url": "www.john.com","content","Johns usage"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://localhost:5000/customer
```

Answer (score 0):

hate to say this but something must have changed between that POST and the PATCH. Maybe you updated the endpoint schema, or there's a typo somewhere. If you don't sort it out try editing your question with the actual settings file (relevant parts), so we can try to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response. The problem is resolved by adding  -H "Content-Type: application/json" to the header. It worked.  There is no typo in the command and it matches the fields in the settings.py.

Comment: Ah right I saw it in the POST request, didn't bother to check the PATCH (damn scrollbars!). Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same problem.

I have created a pull request to update the documentation here : https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/pull/659